# Can not convert from TabActivity to FragmentTabHost

Tags: android, tabactivity, fragment-tab-host

I have a class which extends TabActivity

Because TabActivity is deprecated, i would like to convert it using FragmentTabHost.
The problem is when i launch the app, i get this error.
Because i still a newbie on android, can someone help me how to solve this problem.
Can TabActivity give me some problem in newer devices or can i still use it whiteout problem?

Thank you

This is the log cat

```
05-15 22:22:10.365: E/AndroidRuntime(2452): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-15 22:22:10.365: E/AndroidRuntime(2452): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.wilbur.app.ui.CatalogLocalListActivity cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
05-15 22:22:10.365: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:402)
05-15 22:22:10.365: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost.doTabChanged(FragmentTabHost.java:343)
05-15 22:22:10.365: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost.onAttachedToWindow(FragmentTabHost.java:280)
05-15 22:22:10.365: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:12761)
05-15 22:22:10.365: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2642)
05-15 22:22:10.365: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2649)
05-15 22:22:10.365: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2649)
05-15 22:22:10.365: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2649)
05-15 22:22:10.365: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1470)
05-15 22:22:10.365: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1230)
05-15 22:22:10.365: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5089)
05-15 22:22:10.365: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
05-15 22:22:10.365: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
05-15 22:22:10.365: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:561)
05-15 22:22:10.365: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777)
05-15 22:22:10.365: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-15 22:22:10.365: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-15 22:22:10.365: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-15 22:22:10.365: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
05-15 22:22:10.365: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-15 22:22:10.365: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-15 22:22:10.365: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
05-15 22:22:10.365: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
05-15 22:22:10.365: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this is the activity converted in FragmentTabHost

```
public class CatalogTabHostActivity extends FragmentActivity {

public static final int RESULT_EULA_CANCELED = 100; 

private static final String TAB_LOCAL = "local";

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.catalog_tab_host);
    mInstance = this;
    Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = null;
    if(i!=null){
        extras = i.getExtras();
    }
    FragmentTabHost mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(CatalogTabHostActivity.this, getSupportFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);


    Intent intentLocalCatalog = new Intent(this, CatalogLocalListActivity.class);
    if(extras!=null){
        intentLocalCatalog.putExtras(extras);
    }

    mTabHost.addTab( mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_LOCAL).setIndicator(""), CatalogLocalListActivity.class, null);


    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(0).setVisibility(View.GONE);


}

protected void onResume() {
    if(!GlobalSettings.isAcceptedEULA(this)){
    }else if(!GlobalSettings.isChangeLogShowed(this)){
    //  ChangeLogDialog.show(this);
        ApplicationEx.getInstance().invalidateAutoUpdate();
        GlobalSettings.setChangeLogShowed(this);
    }
    super.onResume();
}



private static CatalogTabHostActivity mInstance;

public static Activity getInstance()
{
    return mInstance;
}

}
```

This is the CatalogLocalListActivity

```
public class CatalogLocalListActivity extends BaseCatalogActivity {

public static final String EXTRA_INVOKE_LOCAL_UPDATE_LIST = "EXTRA_INVOKE_LOCAL_UPDATE_LIST";

private boolean mInvokeSelectCurrent;
private boolean mInvokeUpdateList;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mInvokeSelectCurrent = true;
    Intent data = getIntent();
    if(data!=null){
        mInvokeUpdateList = data.getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_INVOKE_LOCAL_UPDATE_LIST, false);
    }
}

protected void setListView() {
    super.setListView();
    if(mInvokeSelectCurrent){
        mInvokeSelectCurrent = false;
        GlobalSettings.MapPath path = GlobalSettings.getCurrentMap(this);
        String systemMapName = path.getSystemMapName();
        if(systemMapName!=null){
            int position = mAdapter.findItemPosition(systemMapName);
            if(position!=-1){
                mList.setSelection(position);
            }
        }
    }
    if(mInvokeUpdateList){
        mInvokeUpdateList = false;
        invokeSelectUpdateMaps();
    }       
}

protected boolean isCatalogProgressEnabled(int catalogId) {
    return catalogId == CatalogStorage.LOCAL;
}

protected int getEmptyListHeader() {
    return R.string.msg_no_maps_in_local_header;
}

protected int getEmptyListMessage() {
    return R.string.msg_no_maps_in_local;
}

public int getCatalogState(CatalogMap local, CatalogMap remote) {
    return mRemote!=null && mLocal!=null ? mStorageState.getLocalCatalogState(local, remote) : CatalogMapState.CALCULATING;
}

public boolean onCatalogMapClick(CatalogMap local, CatalogMap remote, int state) {
    switch(state){
    case CALCULATING:
        if(local.isAvailable()){
            invokeFinish(local);
        }else{
            invokeMapDetails(local,remote,state);
        }
        return true;
    case OFFLINE:
    case INSTALLED:
    case UPDATE:
        invokeFinish(local);
        return true;
    case IMPORT:
    case DOWNLOAD:
    case DOWNLOAD_PENDING:
    case DOWNLOADING:
    case IMPORT_PENDING:
    case IMPORTING:
    case NEED_TO_UPDATE:
    case NOT_SUPPORTED:
    case UPDATE_NOT_SUPPORTED:
    case CORRUPTED:
        invokeMapDetails(local,remote,state);
        return true;
        // do nothing
    }               
    return true;
}

protected int getDiffMode() {
    return CatalogMapPair.DIFF_MODE_LOCAL;
}

protected int getLocalCatalogId() {
    return CatalogStorage.LOCAL;
}

protected int getRemoteCatalogId() {
return CatalogStorage.ONLINE;
} 

protected int getDiffColors() {
    return R.array.local_catalog_map_state_colors;
}

/****************** MAIN MENU ********************/

private final int MAIN_MENU_UPDATE_MAPS = 1;
private final int MAIN_MENU_DELETE_MAPS = 2;

private final static int REQUEST_UPDATE = 1;
private final static int REQUEST_DELETE = 2;

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.add(0, MAIN_MENU_UPDATE_MAPS, 5, R.string.menu_update_maps).setIcon(R.drawable.icon_tab_import_selected);
    menu.add(0, MAIN_MENU_DELETE_MAPS, 6, R.string.menu_delete_maps).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_delete);
    return true;
}

public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.findItem(MAIN_MENU_UPDATE_MAPS).setEnabled(mMode == MODE_LIST && !mStorage.hasTasks());
    menu.findItem(MAIN_MENU_DELETE_MAPS).setEnabled(mMode == MODE_LIST && !mStorage.hasTasks());
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case MAIN_MENU_UPDATE_MAPS:
        invokeSelectUpdateMaps();
        return true;
    case MAIN_MENU_DELETE_MAPS:
        invokeSelectDeleteMaps();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQUEST_UPDATE:
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!=null){
            String[] names = data.getStringArrayExtra(CatalogMapSelectionActivity.EXTRA_SELECTION);
            for (String systemName : names) {
                mStorage.requestDownload(systemName);
            }
        }
        if(resultCode == CatalogMapSelectionActivity.RESULT_MAP_LIST_EMPTY){
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.msg_no_maps_to_update, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        break;
    case REQUEST_DELETE:
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!=null){
            String[] names = data.getStringArrayExtra(CatalogMapSelectionActivity.EXTRA_SELECTION);
            for (String systemName : names) {
                mStorage.deleteLocalMap(systemName);
            }
        }
        if(resultCode == CatalogMapSelectionActivity.RESULT_MAP_LIST_EMPTY){
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.msg_no_maps_to_delete, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        break;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

private void invokeSelectDeleteMaps() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, CatalogMapSelectionActivity.class);
    i.putExtra(CatalogMapSelectionActivity.EXTRA_TITLE, getText(R.string.menu_delete_maps));
    i.putExtra(CatalogMapSelectionActivity.EXTRA_REMOTE_ID, CatalogStorage.ONLINE);
    i.putExtra(CatalogMapSelectionActivity.EXTRA_REMOTE_MODE, CatalogMapPair.DIFF_MODE_LOCAL);
    i.putExtra(CatalogMapSelectionActivity.EXTRA_FILTER, mActionBarEditText.getText().toString());
    i.putExtra(CatalogMapSelectionActivity.EXTRA_SORT_MODE, CheckedCatalogAdapter.SORT_MODE_COUNTRY);
    startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_DELETE);
}

private void invokeSelectUpdateMaps() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, CatalogMapSelectionActivity.class);
    i.putExtra(CatalogMapSelectionActivity.EXTRA_TITLE, getText(R.string.menu_update_maps));
    i.putExtra(CatalogMapSelectionActivity.EXTRA_REMOTE_ID, CatalogStorage.ONLINE);
    i.putExtra(CatalogMapSelectionActivity.EXTRA_FILTER, mActionBarEditText.getText().toString());
    i.putExtra(CatalogMapSelectionActivity.EXTRA_SORT_MODE, CheckedCatalogAdapter.SORT_MODE_COUNTRY);
    i.putExtra(CatalogMapSelectionActivity.EXTRA_CHECKABLE_STATES, new int[]{ CatalogMapState.UPDATE, CatalogMapState.NEED_TO_UPDATE } );
    i.putExtra(CatalogMapSelectionActivity.EXTRA_VISIBLE_STATES, new int[]{ CatalogMapState.UPDATE, CatalogMapState.NEED_TO_UPDATE } );
    startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_UPDATE);
}   
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation for `FragmentTabHost`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html):

> Special TabHost that allows the use of Fragment objects for its tab content.

You are attempting to put an `Activity` as its tab content. Please convert that to be a `Fragment`.